# ValueError: embedded null byte when opening a file using bytestring Python

Tags: python

I try to open a file (here bytestring is shortened) but get ValueError: embedded null byte

My code:

```
file = b'\x03\x04\x14\x00'

with open(file) as f:
    print(f.name)
```

I get this:

```
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

Comment: It's not the whole bytestring, original bytestring is super long because it's an excel file and it has hundreds of null bytes

Comment: So this bytestring isn't a file name? Why are you using `open` on it at all? Are you trying to pass the actual bytes contained in the file? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm sending a file in bytes format to a server, server receives a file (bytes) and should extract the file name. One of the options is to use this:
with open(bytes) as f: 
    name = f.name

Comment: Perhaps you could try `mode = 'rb'` in `open`, though if these bytes are the whole file rather than the name of the file, I don't think it really makes sense.

Comment: mode = 'rb' did not help

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code; let's go through it. I see three issues.

```py
file = b'\x03\x04\x14\x00'

with open(file) as f:
    print(f.name)
```

1. The `open(file)` requires a filename or path, not bytes.
2. Your `file` is actually the bytes you'd get from running `f.read()`, *after* opening the file.
3. Finally, in `f.name`, the "name" is probably a "property" of a file `Path` (i.e. `from pathlib import Path`).

Typically, the pattern would look more like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

file = Path("/home/user/docs/spreadsheet.csv")
print(file.name)

# Open file in "read-binary" mode, and read all the content into the "bytes_" variable
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    bytes_ = f.read()

print(bytes_)
```